# Reset carousel back to first slide when you swipe passed it - using swiper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

So I have a complex layout I'm trying to build which involves one main carousel going across the x-axis and then two sub carousels going down the y-axis. Here's a fiddle which demonstrates it better - https://jsfiddle.net/anvcmpke/ - which I've done using [swiper.js](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/).

The problem I'm having is that when you scroll to the first y-axis carousel and scroll down and then move on to the second y-axis carousel, when you navigate back to the first y-axis carousel it holds it's position from where you last left it.

What I'm trying to achieve is when you scroll back to the first y-axis carousel after visiting the second y-axis carousel I want the first y-axis carousel to go back to the first slide.

I think I know how to achieve this, by running `mySwiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks);` when you swiper along the x-axis but I don't quite know how to trigger that.Can anyone point me in the right direction as to achieve what I'm after? I'm confusing myself based on all the carousels I'm trying to control.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a pretty simple fix -

```
    horizontalSwiper.on('slideChange', function () {
      verticalSwiper.slideTo(0, 1, false);
      verticalSwiper2.slideTo(0, 1, false);
    });
```